# Comparing two collections using Equator in CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection

Tags: java, generics, collections, interface

I have to compare two collections using Apache CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection.
They are have the same interface Compress and have a method to compare:

```
public boolean isTheSame(Compress compr);
```

But I don't have an idea, how to add an Equator to my code.

**From documentation:**

```
isEqualCollection(Collection<? extends E> a, Collection<? extends E> b, Equator<? 
super E> equator)
Returns true iff the given Collections contain exactly the same elements with exactly the same cardinalities.
```

My code:

```
    return CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(filtLst3, filtLst4, equator);
```

Should I put the Equator's methods in my collection classes?
Or may be I should write something like this (Not working code):

```
...

    Eq equator = new Eq<Compress>();
    return CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(filtLst3, filtLst4, equator);
}

public static class Eq<Compress> implements Equator {

    public boolean equate(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Compress c1 = (Compress) o1;
        Compress c2 = (Compress) o1;

        return c1.isTheSame(c2);
    }

    public int hash(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I will really appreciate any help!

Comment: What do you mean by `Should I put the Equator's methods in my collection classes` ?

Comment: I mean, should I make that my classes implement Equator?

Comment: Do you have any choice?

Comment: Please, if possible, provide example or link, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
 public boolean isTheSame(Collection<? extends Compress> a, Collection<? extends Compress> b) {
        Equator<Compress> compressEquator = new CompressEquator();
        return CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(a, b, compressEquator); 
 }

    public static class CompressEquator implements Equator<Compress> {

    public boolean equate(Compress c1, Compress c2) {
       return c1.isTheSame(c2);
    }
    //
  }
}
```